# Using Max Mind API with an IP Variable

Tags: php, api

Hi I am using the Max Mind API to query an IP Address, now if i am using a single address like below this works perfectly well.

```
$params = getopt('l:i:');
if (!isset($params['l'])) $params['l'] = 'key';
if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = '82.150.248.29';

$query = 'https://geoip.maxmind.com/e?' . http_build_query($params);
```

But what I would like to do is use an already existing piece of code which catches the IP address and place it in to a variable.  However my code below doesn't return any values and just inserts a blank row to the database.

```
$params = getopt('l:i:');
$ip ='83.218.149.79';  //To simulate capturing the ip address
if (!isset($params['l'])) $params['l'] = 'key';
if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = '$ip';

$query = 'https://geoip.maxmind.com/e?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = '$ip';
```

That line is wrong. Variables don't belong between quotes.

```
if (!isset($params['i'])) $params['i'] = $ip;
```

Comment: HI Thanks, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: No it was, after I made your change i forgot to re add the license key  which i had taken out when i copied the code to show here,